# How do you launch terminal (mac) using c code?

Tags: c, macos, terminal, gnome-terminal

I'm porting an app i've been working on from Linux to Mac and i'm having trouble with one specific line:

```
system(gnome-terminal -x sh -c \"/home/mrmartin/NetBeansProjects/Consumer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/consumer\"");
```

Obviously this is because gnome-terminal is gnome linux only but i can't seem to find the Mac equivalent.

Comment: That code you're porting doesn't even target Linux. It targets *GNOME*.

Comment: One issue I see here is many users use a different terminal program, in my case, I use iTerm2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [open](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html), e.g.

```
system("open -a Terminal.app");
```

or

```
system("open -a Terminal.app /path/to/script");
```